# custom facebook role (developer application)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook application which has the need for 2 roles: "basic" for those who need basic commenting ability, and "editor" for those that are approved of to be editors.

I'm hoping I can therefore define an "editor" role somehow in my facebook application (do I use custom actions) and have a newly registered/logged in user of my site be able to request to be an "editor".

Is there a facebook workflow that I can use to not only define a custom role, but also have an event that allows my site to receive an email that a user has requested to be an editor, and then email back to them an approval link to follow if that user is approved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're much better off building that workflow into your application itself rather than (ab)using Facebook roles for the same purpose.

Comment: Agreed!  Please setup your own authorization/roles in your app.  This way your app has more control over what gets seen by whom.